# Bad ( Background image doens't work in github)

Tags: html, css

Hello before this question I was working in one project and i needed use (Background-image) but I can't find why it wasn't work.

Now I write a simple example to see why don't work but it's continue same.

--------------***HTML CODE**-------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1> Title </h1>

</body<
```

-----------------------------*******************----------------------------------
CSS CODE

```
body{
background-color:gray;
   background-image: url("eliana.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

---------------------------******---------------------------

This is the repository, I tried to make the simple example having all in the same folder for avoid the root problem, but really I can't see what happen, Thanks for your support

https://github.com/Hafrancol/Carta.git

Comment: is there a network error in your console? have you tried `url("./eliana.jpg")`?

Comment: Your example works for me (Safari on IOS) but note that background-attachment: fixed can give blurry results on Safari (see [link]https://caniuse.com for list of which browsers support it fully). You have a minor typo at the end of /body with the closing bracket, but that is not causing your problem. I have put a snippet into an answer for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below . This probably way to fix this.

```css
body{
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#7abcff+0,4096ee+100 */
  background:url(https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/arches.png) repeat, #7abcff; /* Old browsers */
  background:url(https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/arches.png) repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7abcff 0%, rgb(255, 5, 5) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background:url(https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/arches.png) repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(255, 5, 5) 0%,rgb(255, 5, 5) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background:url(https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/arches.png) repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgb(255, 5, 5) 0%,rgb(255, 5, 5) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet with your img loaded into imgur and the full Url used. It seems OK on Safari (IOS) though note that it does not support background-attachment: fixed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
body{
background-color:gray;
   background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRgTB.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Title </h1>

</body>
```